# How to execute function connecting to external device by clicking the button in tkinter?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, button

I am using Pycharm to control lock-in. To connect to the device I have defined a function. I want to run the connection by clicking the button. However, when putting the device parameters at the beginning of the code, the connection doesn't wait until I press the button. How to initiate the connection by clicking the button?

I was trying to resolve the problem by removing the device parameters at the beginning of the code and bringing them as arguments of connecting function, but then the following error appeared: Unresolved
references

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import zhinst.core
from zhinst.core import __version__ as zhinst_version
import zhinst.utils
import json

# device parameters
device_id = "dev6534" # Device serial number available on its rear panel.
server_host = "192.168.102.26"
server_port = 8004
interface = "PCIe"
api_level = 6

def connect_to_dev():
    daq = zhinst.core.ziDAQServer(server_host, server_port, api_level)  #create API session
    daq.connectDevice(device_id, interface)
    daq.setInt(f"/{device_id}/system/identify", 1)

    if daq.revision() == daq.getInt("/zi/about/revision"):
        print("LabOne and zhinst.core version match.")
    else:
        labone_version = daq.getString("/zi/about/version")
        labone_revision = daq.getInt("/zi/about/revision")
        print(
            f"zhinst.core version ({zhinst_version}) does not match",
            f"the LabOne version ({labone_version}.{str(labone_revision)[4:]})!",
        )
    import json
    status_flag = json.loads(daq.getString("/zi/devices"))[device_id.upper()]["STATUSFLAGS"]
    if status_flag & 1 << 8:
        print(
        "The device is currently updating please try again after the update "
        "process is complete"
        )
    elif status_flag & 1 << 4 or status_flag & 1 << 5:
        print(
        "The firmware does not match the LabOne version. "
        "Please update the firmware, e.g. in the LabOne UI."
        )
    elif status_flag & 1 << 6 or status_flag & 1 << 7:
        print(
        "The firmware does not match the LabOne version. "
        "Please update LabOne to the latest version from "
        "https://www.zhinst.com/support/download-center."
        )
    else:
        print("The Firmware matches the LabOne version")

##### CONNECTIVITY CHECK #####

(daq, device, props) = zhinst.utils.create_api_session(device_id, api_level, server_host=server_host, server_port=server_port)

zhinst.utils.api_server_version_check(daq)

zhinst.utils.disable_everything(daq, device_id)

root = tk.Tk()

root.title('Resonance Effect of Microcantilever Beam')
root.geometry('1000x800+50+50')
root.resizable(False,False)
root.attributes('-topmost', 1)
root.iconbitmap('C:\\Users\\Ania\\Desktop\\Help_Tools\\zhinst_logo.ico')

# Buttons settings
connect_button = ttk.Button(root, text="connect", command=connect_to_dev("dev6534", "192.168.102.26",  ))
connect_button.pack(ipadx=5, ipady=5, expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```